# Elasticsearch 2.1: how to delete by query using curl

Tags: curl, elasticsearch

I have an _index: varnish_logs and _type: varnish

a field having two different values "server" : "india" and "server" : "usa"

Now I want to delete only the records which are in usa.

I tried using

$ curl -XDELETE 'http://localhost:9200/_all/_query?q=server:usa'

response: No handler found for uri [] and method [DELETE]

[image]
and also tried to delete all the data using query

`curl -XDELETE 'http://localhost:9200/varnish_logs/varnish/_query' -d '`
`{`
   `"query" :{`
        `"match_all" : {}`
    `}`
`}'`

all I get response: found: "false"
 [image]

Please let me know where I'm wrong

Comment: I presume delete by query has been deprecated in versions after 1.5.3 [link] (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/docs-delete-by-query.html)

Comment: @manishrw Thanks I don't get scroll_id concept is there any way to delete all records which match the query

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Elasticsearch has removed the *delete-by-query* functionality. They have instead replaced it by a plugin with same name. It is slower than the previous but fixes the problem elasticsearch had previously.

This [post](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/current/plugins-delete-by-query.html) from elasticsearch might help.

Comment: Thanks. Now its done thanks and yes it is deleting really slow but works great.