# Removing From ElasticSearch by type last 7 day

Tags: elasticsearch

I have different logs in elasticsearch 2.2 separate by 'type'. How can delete all data, only one of type, older one week? thanks

Example of logs:

```js
{
  "_index": "logstash-2016.02.23",
  "_type": "dns_ns",
  "_id": "AVMOj--RqgDl5Axva2Nt",
  "_score": 1,
  "_source": {
    "@version": "1",
    "@timestamp": "2016-02-23T14:37:07.029Z",
    "type": "dns_ns",
    "host": "11.11.11.11",
    "clientip": "22.22.22.22",
    "queryname": "api.bing.com",
    "zonetype": "Public_zones",
    "querytype": "A",
    "querytype2": "+ED",
    "dnsip": "33.33.33.33"
  },
  "fields": {
    "@timestamp": [
      1456238227029
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: please provide more details...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34286357/delete-all-documents-of-a-type-in-elasticsearch-2-1/34286459#34286459) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34185028/elasticsearch-2-1-how-to-delete-by-query-using-curl?rq=1) on how to delete by query. In Elasticsearch 2.*, you might find the [Delete by Query plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/2.0/plugins-delete-by-query.html) useful.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting "types" is no longer directly supported in ES 2.x  A better plan is to have rolling indexes, that way deleting indexes older than 7 days becomes very easy.

Take the example of logstash, it creates an index for every day.  You can then create an alias for `logstash` so that it queries all indexes.  And then when it comes time to delete old data you can simply remove the entire index with:

`DELETE logstash-2015-12-16`

[image]